# knapsack problem data storage from table in a File C

Tags: c, file, computer-science, file-handling, knapsack-problem

I am trying to store data for Value, Weight and Cost from a file containing a table which contains three columns of numbers for Value, Weight and Cost. The table may vary in length (9 or 21 rows) depending on the file chosen by the user.
I am having trouble trying to store the data from this file to use in a brute force function to solve the problem.
This is what I have so far.

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>
     #include <string.h>
     int main()
     {
         int nr_rows;
         int i = 1;
         int j = 2;
         int k = 3;
         int l,m,n = 0;
         int budget_cost;
         int weight_lim;
         char file_name[50];
         float c[nr_rows][3];
         char stringA[20] = "objectsA.txt";
         char stringB[20] = "objectsB.txt";

         printf("Enter the filename containing item listing: ");
         scanf("%s", &file_name);
         if(strcmp(file_name,stringA)==0)
         {
             nr_rows = 9;
         }
         else if(strcmp(file_name,stringB)==0)
         {
             nr_rows = 21;
         }
         printf("The number of rows is %d", nr_rows);
         float value[nr_rows], weight[nr_rows], price[nr_rows];
         FILE *fpointer;
         fpointer = fopen(file_name, "r");
         if(!fpointer)
         {
             printf("The file %s could not be opened.", file_name);
             return 1;
         }
         j=0;
         while(j<nr_rows)                            
         {                                          
             i=0;                      // Skip the first line
             while(i<3)
             {
                 fscanf(fpointer, "%f", &c[j][i]);
                 //printf("%.0f\n", c[j][i]);
                 if(i=1) /* Change this if statement so that 1 ,4 ,7 ,10
                            etc. activates*/
                 {
                     c[j][i] = v[l];
                     l++;
                     printf("%f", v[l]);
                 }
                 else if(i=2)/* Change this if statement so that 2,5,8 etc. 
                                activates*/
                 {
                     c[j][i] = w[m];
                     m++;
                 }    
                 else if(i=3)/* Change this if statement so that 3,6,9 etc. 
                                activates*/
                 {
                     c[j][i] = p[n];
                     n++;
                 }
                 i++;
             }
             j++;
         }
         fclose(fpointer);
```

Comment: I don't see a question here.  Please clarify.

Comment: I edited the indention so everybody can easily review this code.However I think you miss a '}'.I don't touch other peoples code when I edit , therefore you may need to check this yourself.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//1. Read carefully your file name by doing:
scanf("%s", file_name); // instead of scanf("%s", &file_name);

//2. Declare  c[nr_rows][3] only after reading "nr_rows"

//3. The main "while" loop could look like this
while(j < nr_rows)
{
    fscanf(fpointer, "%f %f %f", &c[j][0], &c[j][1], &c[j][2]);
}
// Then,
fclose(fpointer);
```